# Kafka Elasticsearch connector with AWS-ES : NullPointerException in JestElasticsearchClient

Tags: elasticsearch, apache-kafka-connect, aws-elasticsearch

I am trying to test my Kafka connector config with elasticsearch on AWS. While doing this I got following exception :

java.lang.NullPointerException
at

```
io.confluent.connect.elasticsearch.jest.JestElasticsearchClient.getServerVersion(JestElasticsearchClient.java:231)
at io.confluent.connect.elasticsearch.jest.JestElasticsearchClient.(JestElasticsearchClient.java:142)
```

I am using kafka-connect 5.4.0 docker image. Here is the connector config:

```
{
"name": "events-elasticsearch-sink",
"config": {
"connector.class":"io.confluent.connect.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchSinkConnector",
"elastic.security.protocol": "SSL",
"tasks.max": "1",
"topics": "KAFKA_TOPIC",
"key.ignore": "true",
"connection.url": "https://....aws.com",
"type.name": "mvp-audit-trail",
"name": "events-elasticsearch-sink",
"transforms":"InsertMessageTime,ConvertTimeValue,RouteTS",
"transforms.InsertMessageTime.type": "org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.InsertField$Value",
"transforms.InsertMessageTime.timestamp.field": "connector_processing_timestamp",
"transforms.ConvertTimeValue.type": "org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.TimestampConverter$Value",
"transforms.ConvertTimeValue.target.type":"Timestamp",
"transforms.ConvertTimeValue.field":"timestamp",
"transforms.ConvertTimeValue.format": "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'",
"transforms.RouteTS.type":"org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.TimestampRouter",
"transforms.RouteTS.topic.format":"${topic}-${timestamp}",
"transforms.RouteTS.timestamp.format":"yyyy-MM-dd"
}
}
```

This has been tested locally and is working fine. However, when I am trying to connect to AWS ES. We are facing this issue.

Connect service is running inside a Pod and has all access to Elasticsearch. To validate the access, I executed Python script given [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticsearch-service/latest/developerguide/es-request-signing.html). Python script is able to create and read index in elasticsearch.

Could you please help with this?